# TestNG error when executing script in eclipse ide

Tags: selenium, testng

[image]This is the error when I am trying to execute script in selenium ide using testNG

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.12.0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initializeEverything()V
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initialize(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:22)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:97)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Did you mean, you are running testng test cases in selenium IDE?

Comment: yes, i'm running create user account scenario in testNG.

Comment: Is the browser getting launched before this error?

Comment: Nope, nothing happend

Comment: can you try reinstalling testNG in eclipse?

Comment: already tried re-installation but still same problem

Comment: Create a new class, and write a @Test with a syso and check whether this works. If this doesn't work try installing another testNG versions.

Answer (score 2):

it looks really weird that detected version 6.12 but running with the other version.
AFAIK, selenium has an embedded TestNG which definitely older than 6.12.
from the screenshot, could you adjust the library order, to move "TestNG" upper of "Referenced Libraries": right click on the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> on tab "Order and Export", select "TestNG", then click the "Up" button to move it up.
also, could you share the sample project here: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/355, so that probably can conduct a right fix at TestNG Eclipse Plugin

---

Edit:
It's a classpath issue, you need to remove the redundant and old testng-6.0.jar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Softwares/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar"/>
...
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Softwares/selenium-java-3.4.0/client-combined-3.4.0-nodeps.jar"/>
<!-- Nick: you need to remove this entry: testng-6.0.jar, it's recommended to use TESTNG_CONTAINER  -->
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/orange/Downloads/testng-6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.testng.TESTNG_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Code uploaded, please check